# QGIS Atlas legend title width

Tags: qgis, legend, atlas

I want to create an atlas legend with the option "Only show items inside current atlas feature". This works fine.

But for the legend title I want a black background. So far, I used a separate item for the title. 
When selecting the atlas features dynamically, the legend width is changing as well.

Is there a variable such as width that I could use as width for the title element? Or could I draw only the legend title background black?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set a fixed width for the legend, just make sure it is as big as the largest extent that it will dynamically be.

This is set using the *Data defined override* for **Width** in the *Position and size* of the **Legend** *Item Properties*.

[image]

Choose edit and then type in a number. If you just type it in (without the data defined override) it just gets overwritten.

Other than that I don't think there is a better way.